# FirewallD forcing loopback Centos 7 on port 25 email

Tags: email, centos7, port-forwarding, firewalld

So I know this is a firewall rule problem of some sort. I will try to explain as best as I can. I have an environment that is a KVM VM inside a VPS.

**DIAGRAM OF NETWORK**

> VPS-WAN=1.1.1.1  =>  KVM-virbr-Interface=10.0.0.1 =>  KVM-VM 10.0.0.2

I can telnet from anywhere to the internet to hit KVM-VM  due to  these rules.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-forward-port=port=25:proto=tcp:toport=25:toaddr=10.0.0.2 --permanent
```

The problem occurs when sending email from KVM-VM . If I telnet anything on port 25 from this host I am redirected back to myself.

Looking at tcpdump, I can see that the packets are just being redirected to itself. I am for example telneting 8.8.8.8 25 because there is obviously not an smtp service there and my telnet session is being redirected back to myself.

```
5:08:36.439608 IP 10.10.0.2.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [S], seq 688613034, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183513828 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:08:36.439668 IP 10.10.0.1.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [S], seq 688613034, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183513828 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:08:36.439901 IP 10.10.0.2.25 > 10.10.0.2.44558: Flags [S.], seq 1310863117, ack 688613035, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183513829 ecr 1183513828,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:08:36.439927 IP 8.8.8.8.25 > 10.10.0.2.44558: Flags [S.], seq 1310863117, ack 688613035, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1183513829 ecr 1183513828,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:08:36.440127 IP 10.10.0.2.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513829 ecr 1183513829], length 0
05:08:36.440152 IP 10.10.0.1.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [.], ack 1310863118, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513829 ecr 1183513829], length 0
05:08:36.483292 IP 10.10.0.2.25 > 10.10.0.2.44558: Flags [P.], seq 1:35, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513872 ecr 1183513829], length 34: SMTP: 220 mail.axoai.com ESMTP Postfix
05:08:36.483346 IP 8.8.8.8.25 > 10.10.0.2.44558: Flags [P.], seq 1:35, ack 1, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513872 ecr 1183513829], length 34: SMTP: 220 mail.axoai.com ESMTP Postfix
05:08:36.483558 IP 10.10.0.2.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [.], ack 35, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513872 ecr 1183513872], length 0
05:08:36.483582 IP 10.10.0.1.44558 > 10.10.0.2.25: Flags [.], ack 35, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1183513872 ecr 1183513872], length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a destination rule from the WAN ip address like so and remove the old rule.

This rule allows only those packets from the wan , in the parent host to go to the child.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent  --add-rich-rule 'rule family=ipv4 destination address=1.1.1.1  forward-port port=25 protocol=tcp to-port=25 to-addr=10.0.0.2'
```

Edit I also had to add masquerade

```
 firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-masquerade
```